# VBA for excel, creating some sort of dynamic if statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm working on a database-like document for storing items and their information. I'm having some problem thinking on a way to produce a report for these using VBA. Currently I have a user form that has a multipage with tabs for each row of information for the items:

Tabs:
[add all to rep] [add by status] [add by type] [add by serial] [add by expDate]

each tab has different toggle buttons.

At first I wanted just to have the code make a report using a select case with multipage.SelectedItem.index, and I realized that that was going to be very limited on how the report would be. I decided to have an "add page" to the tabs so that you could add different criteria, for example add all the items with  status A with expDate A to expDate B. With this came the realization that I have 6 tabs and I would have to code all the possible IF statements... Now for the plea of help: is there a way to make a dynamic IF or CASE block in which you could have only the "active" or added tabs into the search criteria? the rest of the code would consist in making counting the amount of items  on the worksheet and iterating trough the using a FOR loop and adding them to a Word document as they meet criteria. I don't have a solid code written yet, but what I have looks like this:

In this cpiece of code I tried making a "gathering" function to sort of manage the possible IF statements, depending on which arguments you passed down to it:

```
Private Function advancedGathering(Optional status As String, Optional itemType As String, Optional id As Integer, Optional expDate As Date, Optional holder As String)

Select Case advancedGathering
    Case status <> Null And _
         itemType <> Null And _
         id <> Null And _
         expDate <> Null And _
         holder <> Null

    Case status <> Null And _
         itemType <> Null And _
         id  <> Null And _
         expDate <> Null And _
         holder <> Null

    End Select


End Function
```

It's incomplete as you can see.

And I also have this for the button click event:

```
Private Sub Button_generate_Click()

    Dim row, quantity As Integer

    quantity = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(colHandler.column("id") & 3, colHandler.column("id") & 900)) 'There are less than 900 items, this is just to capture all

    If Toggle_status_ATR.Value = False Or _
       Toggle_type_ATR.Value = False Or _
       Toggle_id_ATR.Value = False Or _
       Toggle_expDate_ATR.Value = False Or _
       Toggle_holder_ATR.Value = False Then

        Select Case MultiPage_main.SelectedItem.Index
            Case 0 'Add All"
                If Toggle_all_addAll.Value = True Then
                    'This is the first tab which I'm not worried about because if selected it will add all the info on the items
                Else

                End If

            Case 1 'Add by Status
                    If Toggle_status_wayOverdue.Value = True Then
                ElseIf Toggle_status_overdue.Value = True Then
                ElseIf Toggle_status_due.Value = True Then
                ElseIf Toggle_status_good.Value = True Then
                ElseIf Toggle_status_valid.Value = True Then
                End If

            Case 2 'Add by Type

            Case 3 'Add by ID

            Case 4 'Add by expDate

            Case 5 'Add by Holder

        End Select

    Else '> Any of the [Toggle_xxx_ATR] buttons are clicked

    End If

Multipage_selection: 'I tried to use GOTO statements


check_valid:

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

I honestly ran out of ideas, I'm not a proficient coder and I've been working with VBA for only a few months as an add on project to my actual job. Any idea helps and thank everyone for your time!

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why would you want to do this in Excel? Access is designed to do this. If you want to create a spreadsheet, you are not designing it in word with tables either, are you?

Comment: I started doing this in excel because that's how we had all the items listed originally and I took it upon myself to better the system. I kind of evolved from there and at first it was a good way but the last few weeks of me trying to code this thing have been hard. So simple answer: I didn't know there was a better way.